# Using ENUM on unique index for multiple columns

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a database with two columns; email address and an enum column for flag setting. I want to be able to add a unique index on one column (`email_addr`) but to only measure if the ENUM column is value `V` (index 1).

```
CREATE TABLE `RegisteredMembers` (
 `reg_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `mem_name` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Surname',
 `mobile` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email_addr` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `member_status` enum('V','B','A','P') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A' 
          COMMENT 'Validated, Blocked, Anonymous, Pending',

 UNIQUE KEY `unique_RegMemId` (`Reg_id`),
 KEY `EmailAddr` (`email_addr`) USING BTREE
) 

ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2292 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

So that rows with `member_status = 'P'` for example can have duplicate email_addr values but rows with `member_status = 'V'` can not be dupliate email_addr values.

I have tried making the above on PhpMyAdmin but it returns various consistency errors or fails due to current data duplication (for non-V ENUM values).

I have [read some posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51850/using-an-enum-as-part-of-an-index-definition) which seem to very broadly show [this can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376583/setting-the-index-on-enum-fields?rq=1) but also that [this might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959034/can-mysql-define-specific-columns-as-unique-based-on-another-column) be possible?

---

I know some of the more aware DB folks here will be asking *"You crazy? Why are you using ENUM at all?"* and I can only say that we are using ENUM as a transitional from a (very!) old Y/N flag system to one with more options in the same column (thus minimising large anounts of PHP column reference updates on the front end).

I/We could easily rebuild the `member_status` ENUM column as an *int* value refering to another table such as a *status table*; but then again the same query comes back:

**I want to index one column as unique *ONLY* based on the value of another column.**

So when `table`.`member_status` == 'V' then `email_addr` must be unique.

Combining the index columns as a single unique column doesn't work as if `table`.`member_status` == 'P' then duplicates of the `email_addr` column can be allowed.

---

Example:

```
`reg_id`  |  `member_status`  |   `email_addr`
----------------------------------------------------------------
    1     |          P        |  me@homere.com
    2     |          A        |  horse@shoes.com        
    3     |          V        |  martin@koolaide.co.uk
    4     |          A        |  me@homere.com           // this is ok.       
    5     |          A        |  horse@shoes.com         // this is ok too
    6     |          B        |  failed@life.org
    7     |          V        |  martin@koolaide.co.uk   // this is invalid.
```

- Can I do this with ENUM?
- If not can I do this with another column type?
- How can I do this if either of the above are "yes"?

Comment: Unique constraints generally can't be conditional. I'd ask why it's important to allow duplicates under some circumstances but not under others.

Comment: Verified members should not be allowed duplicate email addresses. Unverified members it doesn't matter.

Comment: if it doesn't matter, block duplicate addresses regardless.

Comment: This could be solved at the PHP level but that requires numerous extra SQL calls that would add overhead that I would think shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Just have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `email_addr` and be done with it. If someone's already registered, they've already registered. Their membership status seems irrelevant. You should be testing both in PHP and in the database. The PHP test is to surface an error before inserting, but you'll also need to catch an error on insert due to the constraint and rescue accordingly.

Comment: There are other complexities with the data that already exists that simply making the column unique is not a viable solution here.

Comment: You'll have to explain those complexities if you're asking for a solution: We need to understand your constraints. As a technical note I'd strongly advise against using the MyISAM engine. It's antiquated, brittle and doesn't support a lot of features that make relational databases reliable, like transactions and ACID compliance.

Comment: @tadman Yes I noticed that as I wrote the question, it's an old DB that's being dragged kicking and screaming into 2015, my usual engine is `InnoDb` . The complexities comes  from the current live data being used by live customers so changing the data-types or the structure would require lots of backend work that the client will unlikely pay for. I also believe this to be a side avenue; perhaps better to rewrite: How would you set one column to be unique based on the value of another column, new columns can be added but columns can not be removed (yet... as it's live). There is a test site.

Comment: You can set a compound `UNIQUE` index but I'm not sure that's what you want. Remember NULL values in a unique constraint are ignored, so you're allowed duplicates if your secondary component is NULL. You might be able to have an index on, say, `email_addr, verified` where if `verified` is NULL you can have unlimited records, but only one that's set `verified=1`.

Comment: That sounds like what I want; for some reason I did think of `NULL` on one column but then... nope that's ok, I tested it with a new column (boolean) and that worked. Thanks for the logic walk-through

Comment: @tadman if you can compile the above into an answer I can set an answer and "finish" this Q. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been 2 years since this question was ask but need to respond for the sake of other having similar challenge. I almost left this question without an answer till I had to view more comment, and viola! [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) comment.

I had need for similar implementation but not same use case and [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) comment was the exact solution I was looking for. Here is his solution detailed to your question:

> **Note:** In the steps below, I assume the table `RegisteredMembers` already exist without conflicting data. If conflicting data exist you might have to
>   truncate the table to clear all data using by executing `TRUNCATE RegisteredMembers`

**Step 1: Create a compound unique key on `RegisteredMembers` table using the two column `member_status` and `email_addr`**

```
ALTER TABLE `RegisteredMembers` ADD UNIQUE KEY `member_status_is_email_addr` (`member_status`,`email_addr`);
```

**Step 2: Modify `member_status` column to make it nullable, and limit it to only 'V' enum value as for any other enum value will assume null to allow other insertion of same `email_addr` value**

```
ALTER TABLE `RegisteredMembers` CHANGE `member_status` `member_status` ENUM('V') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL;
```

**Step 3: That's all modification your schema needs. Insert `null` in place of 'B','A', and 'P' and 'V' only when verified.**

I already have a working similar implementation. If you have further question on this, kindly comment and I would respond ASAP.

*Credits: [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) Comment on the this question*